# Javascript Focus() does not work on empty textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I'm trying to focus on a textarea when the function below is called. It works as expected when the textarea is filled, but nothing happens when the textarea is empty. I've also tried removing the placeholder, but that made no difference.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Javascript code:

```
focusOnText(sampleId: string){
    var textarea = document.getElementById(sampleId);
    textarea.focus();
```

HTML code:

```
<textarea class="x" id="sampleId"
          [disabled]="!this.data && !this.editable"
          [readOnly]="!this.editable"
          [(ngModel)]="data"
          placeholder="sample input">{{data}}</textarea>
```

EDIT:

I left out the edit button, which sets editable to true and calls the focusOnText function. So when the edit button is clicked, [disabled] is false (since not both conditions for [disabled] to be true are met). Hence, I can focus by actually clicking in the textarea, it just doesn't automatically focus when data is null.

I use both [readOnly] and [disabled] so that I can apply specific styling in different scenarios (textarea is blank and non-editable VS. blank and editable).

Comment: You cannot focus the element when it is disabled. Try `[disabled]="!editable"` or remove the `disabled` attribute completely, since you also set `readonly`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I think I gave too little information. I left out the edit button, which sets editable to true and calls the focusOnText function. 

So when the edit button is clicked, [disabled] is false (since not both conditions for [disabled] to be true are met). In fact, after clicking edit, I can focus the textarea by clicking in it. However, it does not autofocus.

Comment: I updated my answer to take your comment into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you delay slightly the call to `focus()`. You can avoid using `getElementById(id)` with the help of a template reference variable `txt` associated to the `textarea` element and passed as a parameter to the click event handler:

```
<textarea #txt class="x"
          [disabled]="!data && !editable"
          [readOnly]="!editable"
          [(ngModel)]="data"
          placeholder="sample input"></textarea>

<button (click)="editable = true; focusOnText(txt)">Edit text</button>
```

In the code, use `setTimeout()` to delay the call to `focus()`.

```
focusOnText(txt: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    txt.focus();
  });
}
```

If needed, you can set a delay. The example above doesn't specify any delay, but the call is asynchronous nonetheless.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-problem-databinding-tdbpmv) for a demo.

Comment: I'd just add that _no_ element can be focused when disabled (not a `textarea`-specific thing).